# Куда девать исходники сайтов?

Tags: sass

На все есть свои стандарты. Но не смог нигде найти информацию о правильной практике хранения исходников разработки. Допустим у нас есть теоретический сайт, который мы создаем с помощью sass - препроцессора, минификации js и css файлов, и прочее, что не нужно в готовом проекте, но крайне нужно для дальнейшей работы с сайтом. Что в таком случае делать ? Заливать на хостинг и готовые файлы и исходники, в какую то соседнюю папку, или же отдавать исходники человеку просто в зип-архиве ? В первом случае на хостинге будут лишние файлы, во втором случае, исходники с большой вероятностью могут быть утеряны. Как правильно поступать ?

Comment: Для этого есть github

Comment: У подавляющего большинства людей, заказывающих разработку, нет аккаунтов не гитхабе. Значит придется заливать все исходники в публичный репо, вопрос в том, нормально ли вот так сливать все исходники в открытый доступ, и не смогут ли потом это использовать во вред владельцу ?

Comment: Спрашивайте об этом у владельца. Кому-то нормально, кому-то нет

Comment: При нормальной разработке есть полноценный штат разработчиков на постоянном трудоустройстве с сисадмином (иногда несколькими), который управляет связанными с проектом серверами и держит на них всю необходимую инфраструктуру вроде собственного инстанса гитхаба, трекера задач, системы непрерывного развёртывания и корпоративного чата. Но судя по вашему упоминанию "человека", ваша разработка бесконечно далека от нормальной :)

Comment: выделить папку и нажать `delete`

Comment: с недавних пор на гитхабе, а на битбакете уже давно есть бесплатные приватные репы, регистрируйте новый аккаунт и вперед, передавая код - отдаёте аккаунт

Comment: Ну да, вариант с созданием приватного репа и аккаунта под него, вполне имеет право на жизнь. Как вариант, буду рассматривать, благодарю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не обязательно аккаунт отдавать, достаточно передать (transfer) репозиторий с аккаунта на аккаунт. Такая возможность есть и на bitbucket и на github.

Comment: @insolor да, я в курсе, только была речь про то что у клиентов нет аккаунта на гитхабе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну да, вариант: не заплатили - восстановить пароль через почту и вернуть аккаунт себе.

Answer (score 1):

> и прочее, что не нужно в готовом проекте, но крайне нужно для дальнейшей работы с сайтом. Что в таком случае делать ?

Отдавать клиенту, без вариантов, в структуре сайта, либо отдельно zip архивом. Git/диски и прочее допустимо только с явного согласия и согласования с заказчиком.

Принцип один - заказчик получает все связанное с заказом - конечно, почищенное и подготовленное для дальнейшей возможной работы/сопровождения.

Исходники являются непременным условием, если готовый продукт не подразумевает нормальной работы напрямую.

Исходники могут не передаваться, если контракт есть на изготовление и сопровождение - в этом случае передаются исходники и все актуальное в оконечное оформление прекращения сотрудничества.

К исходникам относятся также все, выполненное в рамках заказа - например, логотип и прочее.

Добавлю - как правило, передаче сопуствует информационное письмо/инструкция (документация), в котором содержатся все необходимые сведения для работы с проектом.

То есть - при любом раскладе нужно все красиво и правильно передать и объяснить, а что уж и как дальше (удалять и прочее) - прерогатива заказчика.